# How can I get object data by itself without user_id key?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm trying to query the partnerEmail and my database is structured liked this:

```
users: {
  user_id: {
    partnerEmail: email@email.com
    ...
  }
}
```

I am doing a query like this:

```
firebase
  .database()
  .ref('/users')
  .orderByChild('partnerEmail')
  .equalTo(email)
  .once('value', snapshot => console.log(snapshot.val()));
```

My results from the console log is:

```
(2) [undefined × 1, Object]
user_id: Object {
  partnerEmail: email@email.com
  ...other data
}
```

How can I get the object data by itself without the user_id key? I just want to be able to set a const as everything inside the data and not the key pair. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ,May be it will work

```js
firebase
  .database()
  .ref('/users')
  .orderByKey()
  .orderByChild('partnerEmail')
  .equalTo(email)
  .once('value', snapshot => console.log(snapshot.val()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query result in a list even if there is single search result, then you need to loop through the list to get the data

```
.once('value', snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(data => {
        console.log(data.val());
    }
});
```